# Contar elementos iguales de una columna de una tabla en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Poniendo un ejemplo, yo tengo la siguiente tabla:

**CASA**................................**EXTERIOR**

silla....................................banco

mesa.................................escaleras

sofa...................................luz

silla....................................banco

mesa.................................escaleras

silla....................................banco

mesa.................................escaleras

¿Como podría preguntarle al sistema mediante código SQL que mencione **los elementos que se repiten igual o mas de tres veces de la columna CASA**? Por ejemplo en este caso me tendría que devolver **silla** y **mesa** que son los elementos que se repiten tres o mas veces.

Muchas gracias,
Saludos,

Comment: Hola!, qué has intentado?, acá tienes que usar dos cosas agrupaciones con group by y luego para obtener solo los que se repiten having count. Recuerda que la idea es ayudarte a resolver no hacer el ejercicio por tí. Saludos!

Comment: El ejercicio es bastante más largo y consiste en un relación de diversas tablas en las que deber relacionarlas entre ellas y sacar más información, lo que el primer paso era similar a éste y no sabía como abordarlo. Sabía de usar COUNT pero desconocía lo de group. De todas formas muchas gracias, con esto que me habéis dicho es suficiente. Saludos. @zerocool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT CASA, COUNT(*)`

`FROM TABLA`

`GROUP BY CASA`

`HAVING COUNT(*)>2`

Comment: Hola Roger, las preguntas que lo único que buscan es que les hagamos los deberes no deberian ser respondidas ya que lo unico que haces es crear un efecto llamada. Ten en cuenta que estas preguntas la mayoria de las vecesa acaban cerradas.

Comment: Si fuese solo esto el ejercicio hubiese terminado sin necesidad de acudir aquí pero debido a la cantidad de trabajo simplemente necesitaba una respuesta rápida a un problema en el que me había quedado encallado. El ejercicio que tengo que hacer no se puede comparar con éste ya que debo relacionarlo con distintas tablas y realizar otras operaciones. Solo quería saber como se lograba hacer un contador. Fin. De todas formas gracias a los que han contestado. @Capt.Teach

Comment: Todo esto que mencionas es entendible, pero lo que vale siempre es la pregunta, la comunidad espera que los trabajos escolares o académicos sean acompañados siempre con un intento de resolverlos o acompañado con alguna investigación. De paso, no está de más comentar que las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad por el sistema.

Comment: Tienes razón, debería haber acompañado la pregunta exponiendo un poco el contexto en el que me encontraba, gracias por la aclaración. La próxima vez lo haré ya que es posible que este mensaje haya dado lugar a confusiones ya que, como he dicho anteriormente, no corresponde al ejercicio expuesto. @Patricio Moracho